# Como colocar hint em um spinner?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tenho um Spinner, onde o usuário deverá seleciona o seu sexo: Até o momento tudo funciona bem, porém preciso deixar um hint escrito a palavra sexo no componente spinner, assim como na imagem abaixo:

[image: Exemplo de Spinner com hint]

Código que tenho até o momento:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_sex"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/edittext_email"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
    android:entries="@array/spinner_genre_items"
    android:textColor="@color/h_gray"
    android:textColorHint="@color/h_gray"
    android:textSize="@dimen/h_three"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium">
 </Spinner>
```

Array com os itens do Spinner:

```
<string-array name="spinner_genre_items">
    <item>Masculino</item>
    <item>Feminino</item>
</string-array>
```

Java:

```
private Spinner mSpinnerGender;
mSpinnerGender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_sex);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.spinner_genre_items,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mSpinnerGender.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Você está usando um `ArrayAdapter` ou uma classe herdando `BaseAdapter`?

Comment: Na verdade não estava usando nenhum dos 2. Agora estou usando um ArrayAdapter, atualizei o código na pergunta.

Comment: passe 3 valores para o seu adapter: Masculino, Feminino e Sexo; Set que o valor inicial é a posição(spinner) como sendo 3(sexo). no getCount diga que seu adapter tem tamanho  2(masculino,feminino);

Comment: Neste caso eu não iria usar o array-list para popular o Spinner e sim o ArrayAdapter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complementando a resposta do @CaiqueOliveira: Para conseguir o efeito desejado você pode fazer o seguinte

1. Criar um array de strings onde o primeiro elemento é o *hint*
2. Utilizar o seguinte código para o adapter

   ```
   final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
           this,R.layout.spinner_item,plantsList){

       @Override
       public boolean isEnabled(int position){

           if(position == 0){

               // Disabilita a primeira posição (hint)
               return false;

           } else {
               return true;
           }
       }

       @Override
       public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                   ViewGroup parent) {

           View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
           TextView tv = (TextView) view;

           if(position == 0){

               // Deixa o hint com a cor cinza ( efeito de desabilitado)
               tv.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);

           }else {
               tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
           }

           return view;
       }
   });

   spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
   spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

   spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

       @Override
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           String selectedItemText = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

           if(position > 0){

               // Ação realizada quando um elemento diferente
              // do hint é selecionado
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

       }
   });
   ```

*Obs.:* Retirado e adaptado de http://android--code.blogspot.com.br/2015/08/android-spinner-hint.htmlhttp://android--code.blogspot.com.br/2015/08/android-spinner-hint.html

Answer (score 0):

A maneira mais simples que encontrei foi esta:

Cria um TextView ou LinearLayout e o coloca junto com o Spinner em um RelativeLayout. Inicialmente a textview terá o texto como se fosse a dica "Selecione um ...", após o primeiro clique este TextView fica invisível, desabilitado e chama o Spinner que está logo atrás dele.

**Passo 1:**

No activity.xml que encontra o spinner, coloque:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_hint_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Select..."/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Passo 2:**

Em seu Activity.java:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout ll_hint_spinner;
    private Spinner sp_main;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ll_hint_spinner = findViewById(R.id.ll_hint_spinner);
        sp_main = findViewById(R.id.sp_main);
        //Action after clicking LinearLayout / Spinner;
        ll_hint_spinner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //By clicking "Select ..." the Spinner is requested;
                sp_main.performClick();
                //Make LinearLayout invisible
                setLinearVisibility(false);
                //Disable LinearLayout
                ll_hint_spinner.setEnabled(false);
                //After LinearLayout is off, Spinner will function normally;
                sp_main.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        sp_main.setSelection(position);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                        setLinearVisibility(true);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    //Method to make LinearLayout invisible or visible;
    public void setLinearVisibility(boolean visible) {
        if (visible) {
            ll_hint_spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            ll_hint_spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Exemplo1] [image: Exemplo2] [image: Exemplo3]

Os exemplos das imagens eu usei um Spinner personalizado, mas o resultado do último exemplo será o mesmo.

Nota: Meu exemplo está no github caso queiro: 
https://github.com/MurilloComino/android-spinner-hint

Answer (score -1):

Olá!

Basta adicionar na primeira linha do seu spinner o que você quer e esta linha dos itens ficará visível.